# I am looking into how to get the mouse position in a text field using Sencha

Tags: javascript, extjs, cursor, cursor-position

This is my first post, I can fill in further details if needed.

I am looking to get the xy position of the cursor when either Hour, Minute or Seconds are clicked. I am looking to use the positions for the stepper to act accordingly. The current code just responds with undefined. I am getting undefined because I am using extjs 4.2.2

```
      {
        xtype: 'spinnerfield',
        itemId: 'time',
        name: 'intime',
        width: 125,
   listeners: {
    mousemove: {
        element: 'el',
        fn: function(e){
           var event = e.event;
           console.log(event.clientX);    
        }
    }
},
     step:1,
     value:"11:11:21",
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RichardErickson that's 'MCVE'.*

Comment: @RichardErickson Thanks! I have provided a bit more looking at the MCVE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `mousemove` event listener to the `el` (or `inputEl`), for example:

```
xtype: 'textfield',
listeners: {
    mousemove: {
        element: 'el',
        fn: function(e){
           console.log(e.event);    
        }
    }
}
```

A working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/uke

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow is amazing! I been banging my head for two days trying to figure this out. I Got it thanks to @CD.. I could use `mousedown:` to determine where in the box is clicked and use `event.clientX` to capture the X position. In extjs 4.2.2 you can use `e.getX()`